# How to remove/drop rows of nothing and NaN in Julia dataframe?

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a df which contains, `nothing`, `NaN` and `missing`. to remove rows which contains `missing` I can use `dropmissing`. Is there any methods to deal with `NaN` and `nothing`?

Sample df:

```
│ Row │ x       │ y    │
│     │ Union…? │ Char │
├─────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ missing │ 'b'  │
│ 3   │ 3.0     │ 'c'  │
│ 4   │         │ 'd'  │
│ 5   │ 5.0     │ 'e'  │
│ 6   │ NaN     │ 'f'  │
```

Expected output:

```
│ Row │ x   │ y    │
│     │ Any │ Char │
├─────┼─────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0 │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ 3.0 │ 'c'  │
│ 3   │ 5.0 │ 'e'  │
```

What I have tried so far,
Based on my knowledge in Julia I tried this,

```
df.x = replace(df.x, NaN=>"something", missing=>"something", nothing=>"something")
print(df[df."x".!="something", :])
```

My code is working as I expected. I feel it's ineffective way of solving this issue.
Is there any separate method to deal with nothing and NaN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do e.g. this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=[1,missing,3,nothing,5,NaN], y='a':'f')
6×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y    │
│     │ Union…? │ Char │
├─────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ missing │ 'b'  │
│ 3   │ 3.0     │ 'c'  │
│ 4   │         │ 'd'  │
│ 5   │ 5.0     │ 'e'  │
│ 6   │ NaN     │ 'f'  │

julia> filter(:x => x -> !any(f -> f(x), (ismissing, isnothing, isnan)), df)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y    │
│     │ Union…? │ Char │
├─────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ 3.0     │ 'c'  │
│ 3   │ 5.0     │ 'e'  │
```

Note that here the order of checks is important, as `isnan` should be last, because otherwise this check will fail for `missing` or `nothing` value.

You could also have written it more directly as:

```
julia> filter(:x => x -> !(ismissing(x) || isnothing(x) || isnan(x)), df)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y    │
│     │ Union…? │ Char │
├─────┼─────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0     │ 'a'  │
│ 2   │ 3.0     │ 'c'  │
│ 3   │ 5.0     │ 'e'  │
```

but I felt that the example with `any` is more extensible (you can then store the list of predicates to check in a variable).

The reason why only a function for removing `missing` is provided in DataFrames.jl is that this is what is normally considered to be a valid but desirable to remove value in data science pipelines.

Normally in Julia when you see `nothing` or `NaN` you probably want to handle them in a different way than `missing` as they most likely signal there is some error in the data or in processing of data (as opposed to `missing` which signals that the data was just not collected).

Comment: is it possible to execute your suggestion using column number rather than name ? For example, `df[:, 1]` .

Comment: yes - just use column number.

Comment: Thanks @BogumilKaminski

If someone is looking for the syntax using column number:
`filter( [1]=> x -> !any(f -> f(x), (ismissing, isnothing, isnan)), df)`

Comment: you do not need to write `[1]`, just `1` is enough